# Error while configuring apache ant on Ubuntu

Tags: android, python, ubuntu, ant, kivy

I am trying to configure apache ant in my Ubuntu for python-for-android, as it is one of its [prerequisites](http://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-android.html#packaging-your-application-into-apk).

I followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wV8OI8j0c0M) tutorial on YouTube but got an error at the end. Whenever I type ant on the terminal it shows this error.

```
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_45/jre/bin/java: 1: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_45/jre/bin/java: : not found
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_45/jre/bin/java: 1: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_45/jre/bin/java: : not found
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_45/jre/bin/java: 1: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_45/jre/b@@@@@@@��@@@@ |� 
@@DDP�td��@�@6643Q�td/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2GNU GNU�t�)N�ݓ��;r�Z��?h:    Directory nonexistent
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_45/jre/bin/java: 1: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_45/jre/bin/java: ELF: not found
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_45/jre/bin/java: 1: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_45/jre/bin/java: �: not found
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_45/jre/bin/java: 3: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_45/jre/bin/java: �: not found
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_45/jre/bin/java: 1: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_45/jre/bin/java: Syntax error: end of file 
unexpected (expecting ")")
```

**What I am Doing:**

```
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_45

export PATH=${PATH}:${JAVA_HOME}/bin

export ANT_HOME=/usr/apache/apache-ant-1.9.4

export PATH=${PATH}:${ANT_HOME}/bin
```

**EDIT:**

Here is the Traceback and is same for **Buildozer** and **Python-for-Android.** I tried to build apk from using both but error is same.
It shows the same error as above before command fails and terminates and shows the traceback on the terminal.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "build.py", line 508, in <module>
make_package(args)
  File "build.py", line 357, in make_package
subprocess.check_call([ANT, arg])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 540, in check_call
raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['ant', 'debug']' returned non-zero exit status 2
```

Can anybody help??

Comment: I think ant is included in the android SDK, which is probably easy to install in Ubuntu. If you use the buildozer tool, it will automatically download and configure it.

Comment: @inclement Same error is displayed on using buildozer. Also please see the **edit**

Comment: Weird. What is the machine you're trying to build on? (OS, version, architecture)

Comment: @inclement Ubuntu 14.04, 32-bit, Intel® Core™ i3-2328M CPU @ 2.20GHz × 4

Comment: @inclement did you figure it out?

Comment: No, I'm afraid I don't know what's wrong

Comment: @inclement It's ok, I should try using the prebuilt Kivy Android VM image. That should work. Thanks

Comment: @inclement do you think I should open an issue in python for android or bulldozer?. But it seems like that the problem is on my side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Ubuntu 14.04, 32-bit

Looks like you installed **64-bit** Java 8 on **32-bit** Ubuntu!

I had exactly the same error message, it solved after I replaced x64 Java dist with i586 (32-bit) dist. It was not related to Python, Android or Buildozer (I even had not had them installed on my machine).

Comment: Well, I guess you are right!, I don't have memories of this error, but I think I might have done this mistake and also as you say that you were facing the same problem without buildozer or py4a installed so this could be the solution. Thank you  +1

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message ("subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['ant', 'debug']' returned non-zero exit status 2") and the solution for me was to start up the GUI by calling

```
~/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-21/tools/android
```

and install the "Android SDK Build-Tools". A bit further up in the log file the missing build-tools were mentioned in my error log.

HTH.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it, then let you know.